# Algorithmically recover the $l'$-adic Galois representation from the $l$-adic one (assuming the Tate conjecture)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algorithms, galois-representations, motives

Let $E$ be a number field. For any finite Galois extension $E\subset F$ there is a continuous homomorphism $\pi_F:\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{E}/E)\to \mathrm{Gal}(F/E)$.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $E$. For any prime $l$ there is a continuous homomorphism $\rho_l:\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{E}/E)\to GL(H^i(X_{\overline{E}}, \mathbb{Q}_l))$. Assuming the Tate conjecture it should be possible to recover $\rho_{l'}$ for any $l'\neq l$ from $\rho_l$.

Suppose there is an oracle that given a finite Galois extension $E\subset F$ and an element $x\in \mathrm{Gal}(F/E)$ spits out the smallest closed ball in $GL(H^i(X_{\overline{E}}, \mathbb{Q}_l))$ containing $\rho_l(\pi_F^{-1}(x))$. Can you answer an analogous query for $\rho_{l'}$ by only making finitely many queries to the oracle?

Comment: Do we know $i$?

Comment: @WillSawin sorry, yes it is a fixed positive integer

Comment: Then you can calculate Frobenius traces. However, not knowing the level of the representation might still be tough.